# @Input variables inside UI components return null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

Hint: Im very new to angular. I hope this question gets answered, as its the most detailed explanation of my issue I can give with my current knowledge/vocabulary in Angular.

I have the following Setup:

My App component defines a PageNavigation array and fills it in the constructor:

**PageNavigation Interface**

```
import {Route} from "@angular/router";

export interface PageNavigation {
  displayName : string;
  route : Route;
}
```

**App Component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {PageNavigation} from "src/app/navigation/page-navigation";
import {TemplatesComponent} from "src/app/pages/templates/templates.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {

  pageNavigations: PageNavigation[];

  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.pageNavigations = [

      {displayName: "Templates", route: {path: "templates", component: TemplatesComponent}}
    ]

    this.pageNavigations.forEach(pageNavigation => { //<-- I use the Array for Routing but that's probably not interesting for my problem
      this.router.config.push(pageNavigation.route);
    });
  }
}
```

I then want to create a Sidebar inside my App Component, and hand over the array

**SideBar Component**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {PageNavigation} from "src/app/navigation/page-navigation";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'tara-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.less']
})
export class SidebarComponent {
  public selectedRoute?: any;

  constructor(public router : Router) { }

  @Input('pageNavigations') pageNavigations : PageNavigation[] | any;


  navigate(): void {
alert(this.selectedRoute);
    // this.router.navigate([this.selectedRoute]).then(function () {
    //   // success
    // }, function () {
    //   // error
    // });
  }
}
```

The corresponding html:

**app.component.html**

```
<tara-sidebar [pageNavigations]="pageNavigations"></tara-sidebar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In the app.component.html I just "hand" the values over

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<p-listbox [options]="pageNavigations" [(ngModel)]="selectedRoute" optionLabel="displayName" optionValue="route" (ngModelChange)="navigate()" ></p-listbox>
```

In the SideBar, I create a prime-ng listbox. It displays the correct Label (in my case "Templates"). However, clicking on it, triggering the navigate() method, I get an alert with either "null" or "[object] [object]" (it alternates between the two, meaning first click = null, second = [object] [object], third = null,...

If possible, can you please explain me whats going on, as I expected to either always get null (with Input beeing "triggered" after the navigate()), or the code to just be working and giving me the data I have clicked on.

[image: Clicked on Templates first time, alert object object]

Clicked on Templates first time

[image: Clicked on Templates second time, alert null]
Clicked on Templates secondtime
I have already tried changing the variable type of selectedRoute from any to PageNavigation, but without success it just was giving me undefined in the alert.

Answer (score 1):

This is can happen because an alert gets the old value of selectedRoute. Try to do this:

```
navigate(value): void {
  alert(value);
}
```

and inside a template:

```
(ngModelChange)="navigate($event)"
```

Comment: I tried it but it had the same behaviour, btw i implemented the method like this

Comment: navigate($event : any) : void {
alert($event);
}

Answer (score 0):

As the returned type of the listbox wasnt PageNavigation but route, when I used alert(value.path) I was presented with a value. However, it still works only once and after that returns null and throwing an error...